# Rotate image "overlaps" other html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotatetransform

I want to rotate an image by clicking in a button but when I do that the image overlaps the buttons. How can I do that?

**My code and example** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jj03b17n/5/) (http://jsfiddle.net/jj03b17n/5/).

**What is happening:**

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

**JS rotation code:**

```
        $(optionsPreview.rotateRightBt).unbind("click").click(function () {
                var deg = $(optionsPreview.img).data('rotate') || 0;

                if (deg == 0) deg = 90;
                else deg = deg + 90 == 360 ? 0 : deg + 90

                $(optionsPreview.img).data('rotate', deg);

                var rotate = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
                $(optionsPreview.img).css({
                    '-webkit-transform': rotate,
                    '-moz-transform': rotate,
                    '-o-transform': rotate,
                    '-ms-transform': rotate,
                    'transform': rotate
                });
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: I put a `'z-index': '10'` into `$(optionsPreview.img).css({...}`s, and [it seems to do the trick](http://jsfiddle.net/jj03b17n/).

Comment: @Teemu in what browser you do that? I'm using Chrome and when I click to rotate right or left the problem keeps the same

Comment: I'm on FireFox 40.0.3, didn't test on other browsers yet ... Indeed, no change on Chrome, and IE11 fails to show the slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I used JS to change the image container height to it rotation. So when image is in a vertical position, the image container height change to the image width. Like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj03b17n/6/)):

```
$(optionsPreview.rotateRightBt).unbind("click").click(function () {
    var deg = $(optionsPreview.img).data('rotate') || 0;

    if (deg == 0) deg = 90;
    else deg = deg + 90 == 360 ? 0 : deg + 90

    $(optionsPreview.img).data('rotate', deg);

    var rotate = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    $(optionsPreview.img).css({
        '-webkit-transform': rotate,
        '-moz-transform': rotate,
        '-o-transform': rotate,
        '-ms-transform': rotate,
        'transform': rotate
    });

    if (deg == 90 || deg == 270) {
        var width = $(optionsPreview.img).width();
        $($(optionsPreview.img).parent()).css("height", width + "px");
    }
    else
        $($(optionsPreview.img).parent()).css("height", "auto");

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the  `margin-top` of the `.tdBarPreview` using jQuery by getting the current size of the image, for example if the image isn't zoomed at all then the following would work, now  when the image is zoomed, get its size and change the following `margin-top` property accordingly.

```
.tdBarPreview
{ 
    display:block;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: I already tried that and don't solve the problem. If you rotate the image and zoom it the problem keeps the same (jsfiddle.net/jj03b17n/4).

Answer (score 0):

@Ninita, when you try to rotate an element using css rotate, the pivot of the rotation is at the center of the element. If you look into your jsfiddle code (http://jsfiddle.net/bjLqztdw/), the pivot point of rotation is at center which is at the location where the yellow 'O' is present.

You can change the location of the pivot so that the rotation will vary as per pivots position.

To change pivots position you have to use "-webkit-transform-origin" style.

Updated your JSfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/bjLqztdw/1/). You can experiment in changing the pivot point.

```
$(optionsPreview.img).css({
 '-webkit-transform': rotate,
 '-moz-transform': rotate,
 '-o-transform': rotate,
 '-ms-transform': rotate,
 'transform': rotate,
 '-webkit-transform-origin': '90% 30%',
});
```

Reference:

Comment: Thanks @Kalyan Kumar S but that doen't solves the problem. When we rotate the image it must not be below the slider and the buttons like I show in the images. The "height" of the image container must adapt to the change.

Comment: Check the updated jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/bjLqztdw/2/). This only works for your jsfiddle code. If your case is to handle all scenarios, you have to change the pivot points dynamically based on the distance.